# SharePoint Transaction Log Size in High Availability Group

Tags: backup, sql

I know SharePoint Config transaction logs tends to grow quickly when in Full Recovery mode, we have been cleaning it out by swapping the database recovery to simple mode, running a backup, the switching it back to Full after as most articles on the topic suggest.

Recently we have moved the SharePoint databases into AlwaysOn High Availability groups. I have now noticed you cannot switch to simple mode while being a member of a HA group. The new process seems to be, remove it from HA, follow original instructions, re-add to HA.

Is there a better way to have HA groups and not have to deal with the transaction logs getting out of control every two weeks?

Comment: do you have any maintinance job on the database/server, which perform full backup of the Tlogs then shrink it? http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/44943/transaction-log-maintanance-while-using-alwayson-availability-group

Comment: We weren't going that direction for backups, but it looks like we may have to. Thanks.

Comment: in other ways you have to break the HA all the time, i think backup is better options, take the backup shrink it and may be day later delete the backup files...:)